# IntelliJ syntax highlighing stops after 5 symbols

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea, flex-lexer, intellij-plugin

DISCLAIMER: This question is mainly directed to people that have at least basic knowledge about plugin creation for the IntelliJ platform.

To ease myself into plugin making, i decided to create a plugin that highlights `.mcfunction` code. (Minecraft commands)

My code works great as long as keywords are less than 5 symbols long. However, keywords longer than 4 symbols does not get highlighted before they are reloaded.

---

**Let me demonstrate:**

[Image: Code when typed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjsCW.png)

[Image: Code after reloading file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wheV.png)

Nothing else has been done here apart from reloading the file. This only happens on keywords longer than 4 symbols. In the following example, `function` and `test` share the same syntax highlighting code:

[Image: Code when typed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8pJy.png)

[Image: Commenting and uncommenting also fixes the highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kNMX.png)

[Image: Correct highlighthing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An4GY.png)

---

#### My code

In `Minecraft.flex`, the JFlex file:

```java
package org.intellij.sdk.language;

import com.intellij.lexer.FlexLexer;
import com.intellij.psi.tree.IElementType;
import org.intellij.sdk.language.psi.MinecraftTypes;
import com.intellij.psi.TokenType;

%%

%class MinecraftLexer
%implements FlexLexer
%unicode
%function advance
%type IElementType

WHITE_SPACE=[ \t\n\r]+
END_OF_LINE_COMMENT=("#")[^\r\n]*
COMMAND=execute|function|test
ARGUMENT=at|as|run
SELECTOR=@e|@a|@p|@s

%%

<YYINITIAL>
{
    {WHITE_SPACE}         { return TokenType.WHITE_SPACE; }
    {END_OF_LINE_COMMENT} { return MinecraftTypes.COMMENT; }
    {COMMAND}             { return MinecraftTypes.COMMAND; }
    {ARGUMENT}            { return MinecraftTypes.ARGUMENT; }
    {SELECTOR}            { return MinecraftTypes.SELECTOR; }
}

[^] { return TokenType.BAD_CHARACTER; }
```

In `Minecraft.bnf`, the Grammar Kit file:

```
{
    parserClass="org.intellij.sdk.language.parser.MinecraftParser"

    extends="com.intellij.extapi.psi.ASTWrapperPsiElement"

    psiClassPrefix="Minecraft"
    psiImplClassSuffix="Impl"
    psiPackage="org.intellij.sdk.language.psi"
    psiImplPackage="org.intellij.sdk.language.psi.impl"

    elementTypeHolderClass="org.intellij.sdk.language.psi.MinecraftTypes"
    elementTypeClass="org.intellij.sdk.language.psi.MinecraftElementType"
    tokenTypeClass="org.intellij.sdk.language.psi.MinecraftTokenType"
}

minecraftFile ::= item*

private item ::= (COMMAND|ARGUMENT|SELECTOR|COMMENT)
```

In `MinecraftSyntaxHighlighter.java`, the file that handles the highlighting:

```java
package org.intellij.sdk.language;

import com.intellij.lexer.Lexer;
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.DefaultLanguageHighlighterColors;
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.HighlighterColors;
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.colors.TextAttributesKey;
import com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.SyntaxHighlighterBase;
import com.intellij.psi.TokenType;
import com.intellij.psi.tree.IElementType;
import org.intellij.sdk.language.psi.MinecraftTypes;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import static com.intellij.openapi.editor.colors.TextAttributesKey.createTextAttributesKey;

/**
 * @author Soni
 */

public class MinecraftSyntaxHighlighter extends SyntaxHighlighterBase
{
    public static final TextAttributesKey COMMAND = createTextAttributesKey("MINECRAFT_COMMAND", DefaultLanguageHighlighterColors.KEYWORD);
    public static final TextAttributesKey ARGUMENT = createTextAttributesKey("MINECRAFT_ARGUMENT", DefaultLanguageHighlighterColors.INSTANCE_METHOD);
    public static final TextAttributesKey SELECTOR = createTextAttributesKey("MINECRAFT_SELECTOR", DefaultLanguageHighlighterColors.INSTANCE_FIELD);
    public static final TextAttributesKey COMMENT = createTextAttributesKey("MINECRAFT_COMMENT", DefaultLanguageHighlighterColors.LINE_COMMENT);
    public static final TextAttributesKey BAD_CHARACTER = createTextAttributesKey("MINECRAFT_BAD_CHARACTER", HighlighterColors.BAD_CHARACTER);

    private static final TextAttributesKey[] COMMAND_KEYS = new TextAttributesKey[]{COMMAND};
    private static final TextAttributesKey[] ARGUMENT_KEYS = new TextAttributesKey[]{ARGUMENT};
    private static final TextAttributesKey[] SELECTOR_KEYS = new TextAttributesKey[]{SELECTOR};
    private static final TextAttributesKey[] COMMENT_KEYS = new TextAttributesKey[]{COMMENT};
    private static final TextAttributesKey[] BAD_CHAR_KEYS = new TextAttributesKey[]{BAD_CHARACTER};
    private static final TextAttributesKey[] EMPTY_KEYS = new TextAttributesKey[0];
    
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Lexer getHighlightingLexer()
    {
        return new MinecraftLexerAdapter();
    }
    
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public TextAttributesKey[] getTokenHighlights(IElementType tokenType)
    {
        if (tokenType.equals(MinecraftTypes.COMMAND))       return COMMAND_KEYS;
        else if (tokenType.equals(MinecraftTypes.ARGUMENT)) return ARGUMENT_KEYS;
        else if (tokenType.equals(MinecraftTypes.SELECTOR)) return SELECTOR_KEYS;
        else if (tokenType.equals(MinecraftTypes.COMMENT))  return COMMENT_KEYS;
        else if (tokenType.equals(TokenType.BAD_CHARACTER)) return BAD_CHAR_KEYS;
        else return EMPTY_KEYS;
    }
}
```

---

This only affects the actual highlighting. Using the *PsiViewer* plugin, I could see that the PSI elements updated as they should when writing the code.

Let me know if you want me to include more code in the question or if you need clarification.

This has caused me some real headaches. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The best place for such questions would be https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development.

Comment: i was going to crosspost it there later today :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in the target group for this question, since I have no experience with IntelliJ, much less with writing custom syntax highlighters. But I took a look at your code, anyway.

Your custom lexer only recognises a handful of special tokens. Every character which does not match one of these is flagged as an error. That's a lot of errors, and it wouldn't surprise me if there is a point at which IntelliJ throws up its metaphoric hands in desperation and decides to stop trying to parse a line with so many errors. (Four is a pretty common threshold value.)

I'd suggest trying to be more generous about what is accepted without error by the lexer (and parser, if there is one). In addition to matching the particular keywords you're interested in, match any valid identifier or number. Match operator characters and parentheses. And whatever passes for a string literal in the language you're syntax highlighting. That's not a lot of work, and it has a better probability of success (at least in the theoretical world I carry around inside my head).

Comment: that seems like a good idea. can you give any explicit examples of what I could do? I'm gonna do brackets, parentheses and quotation mars, should I do something more than that? as I said, I'm still pretty new to all of this :)